# Artifactory '404 not found' error in Pipelines build step

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-pipelines

I am trying to setup JFrog Pipelines. I am new to this so starting small with a pipleline that just has a single npm build step. The source code is taken from github. When I run the pipeline, I get a 404 not found error in the `artifactory_configure` task. I double checked the Artifactory Integration but the error persists.

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you include the Artifactory context as part of the URL when creating the Artifactory integration. For example:

```
https://xxx.jfrog.io/artifactory
```